# Classifying 1 cycle permutation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations

Given a permutation matrix that is not full rank, is there a linear algebraic and corresponding algebraic criterion to tell if matrix contains more than one disjoint non-trivial cycle or exactly one non-trivial cycle?

Is there a criteria to tell $X,Y$ have unique cycles of length $d_x,d_y$ respectively by looking at $X\otimes Y$?

Example:
Consider 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0\\
1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1\\
0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

This matrix embeds 1st row->2nd row->6th row->8th row->5th row->1st row cycle (essentially a 5-cycle in $8\times 8$ matrix). Hence we have a non-trivial $5$-cycle.

In above matrix, if (3,3),(4,4),(7,7) entry is 1, we still get a 5 cycle with 3 fixed points.

On other hand if (4,3),(3,4) entry is 1 and (7,7) entry is 0, we obtain disjoint 2 and 5 cycles with no fixed points (turning (7,7) to 1 gets you a fixed point).

When previous example acts on left on
\begin{pmatrix}
a1& a2& a3& a4& a5& a6& a7& a8\\
 b1& b2& b3& b4& b5& b6& b7& b8\\
 c1& c2& c3& c4& c5& c6& c7& c8\\
 d1& d2& d3& d4& d5& d6& d7& d8\\
 e1& e2& e3& e4& e5& e6& e7& e8\\
 f1& f2& f3& f4& f5& f6& f7& f8\\
 g1& g2& g3& g4& g5& g6& g7& g8\\
 h1& h2& h3& h4& h5& h6& h7& h8
\end{pmatrix}

we get
\begin{pmatrix}
e1& e2& e3& e4& e5& e6& e7& e8\\
 a1& a2& a3& a4& a5& a6& a7& a8\\
 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
 h1& h2& h3& h4& h5& h6& h7& h8\\
 b1& b2& b3& b4& b5& b6& b7& b8\\
 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
 f1& f2& f3& f4& f5& f6& f7& f8
\end{pmatrix}

Acting on left $5$ times gives\begin{pmatrix}
 a1& a2& a3& a4& a5& a6& a7& a8\\
 b1& b2& b3& b4& b5& b6& b7& b8\\
 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
 e1& e2& e3& e4& e5& e6& e7& e8\\
 f1& f2& f3& f4& f5& f6& f7& f8\\
 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
 h1& h2& h3& h4& h5& h6& h7& h8
\end{pmatrix}

cross posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1149588/classifying-1-cycle-permutation-matrices

Comment: You can just see if the characteristic polynomial is of the form $x^r(x^s - 1)$, where $r + s = n$.  I think this criterion should be necessary and sufficient.

Comment: so we cannot say anything linear algebraically?

Comment: I'm not sure why an explicit condition on the characteristic polynomial doesn't suffice.  Can you clarify what you mean by "linear algebraically"?

Comment: something intrinsicaally matrix theoretic instead of using polynomial dictionary?

Comment: Yeah, here's an answer: let $X$ be your matrix, and let the number of "1"s be $d$.  A matrix is a cycle if and only if there are no "1"s on the diagonal of $X^k$ for $k < d$, and all the "1"s of $X^d$ are on the diagonal.

Comment: So $Tr(X^k)\in\{0,d\}$?

Comment: Could I ask if same criteria could hold for $X\otimes Y$? where $X$ has an unique cycle and $Y$ has unique cycle?

Comment: I suppose that is another way to phrase it.  I don't have an answer to your second question and maybe you want to move it to the question anyway.

Comment: That is $Tr((X\otimes Y)^k)\in\{0,d_1d_2\}$? Isn't $Tr(((X\otimes Y)^k)=(X^k\otimes Y^k)=Tr(X^k)Tr(Y^k)\in\{0,d_1d_2\}$?

Comment: @JohnBinder Am I wrong? Your solution seems to work here as well?

Comment: You could convert to an answer. I could close. What is interesting is following. Using to find number of diconnected components of graph, we use betti numbers. It seems that Tr suffices in case situations of cycle.

Comment: My apologies, $Tr(X^k)\in \{0, d\}$ is not sufficient.  If $X$ has a pair of two-cycles, then $\Tr(X^k) \in \{0, 4\}$. You need to check that $\Tr(X^2) = 0$ and $\Tr(X^4) = 4$.

Comment: No actually $Tr(X^2)\neq 0$. So does inequality $Tr(X^4)\neq 0$.

Comment: Ack. Apologies.  $Tr(X^2) \neq 0$.  You need $\Tr(X^k) = 0$ for all $k < d$.  I will move this to an answer.

Comment: so does not work?

Comment: I think it detects disjoint cycles upto uniform size. That is, if it contains cycles which are same size, it will still work since range of $Tr$ is $2$-valued.

Comment: @JohnBinder your first condition on the characteristic polynomial is not "if and only if", since it allows to have nontrivial blocks with the zero eigenvalue in the Jordan normal form...

Comment: IMHO such matrices are not even called permutational, to begin with.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko I was operating under the assumption that all such permutation matrices were semisimple, from the statement of the problem, that the matrices in question were semisimple.  I should have stated this to begin with, but if this assumption is relaxed then you are correct.